# Can we use system.assert followed by system.assertEquals?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

```
 pse__Timecard_Header__c th1 = new pse__Timecard_Header__c(
                CurrencyIsoCode         = 'USD',
                pse__Project__c         = project.ID,
                pse__Resource__c        = pmResource.Id,
                pse__Monday_Hours__c    = 8,
                pse__Tuesday_Hours__c   = 8,
                pse__Wednesday_Hours__c = 8,
                pse__Thursday_Hours__c  = 8,
                pse__Friday_Hours__c    = 8,
                pse__Start_Date__c      = Date.today().toStartOfWeek(),
                pse__End_Date__c        = Date.today().toStartOfWeek()+6
            );
             insert th1;
           System.runAs(pmUser) 
            {
                 delete th1;
                 system.assert([select ID from pse__Timecard_Header__c WHERE Id = :th1.Id ].IsEmpty());
           }
            system.assertEquals(th1.Period__c, c2g__codaPeriod__c.Id);
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use `System.assert` followed by `System.assertEquals`. There is no reason that they both can't be called from the same method.

In your particular case you delete `th1`.  Then you query from the DB and verify that it is empty with the following:

```
system.assert([select ID from pse__Timecard_Header__c WHERE Id = :th1.Id ].IsEmpty());
```

That works, because it has been deleted from the DB.

You then assert against the `th1` variable that is in memory from the query prior to the delete with the following:

```
system.assertEquals(th1.Period__c, c2g__codaPeriod__c.Id);
```

That works because `th1` is an in memory variable that was set prior to the deletion and still has those values in it.  It is not automatically made null or something like that, if that's what you were thinking.